# Javascript: console logging

Tags: javascript, logging

I use `console.log` in my JS files to trace the application.

The problem: logs are in production environment.
How can I remove lines like `console.log` from code?

P.S. Please do not advice text solutions like `find + xargs + grep -v`.

Comment: You want to remove the lines from your code, or you don't want console output to be printed?

Comment: Note that there are other methods as well (`console.dir` for example).

Comment: I think, it's better to remove these lines from code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can disable them with

```
console.log=function(){}
```

But the lines will be there unsless you delete them manually.

Comment: _Uncaught TypeError: Property 'log' of object #<Console> is not a function_ Perhaps `console.log = function(){};` instead...

Comment: Yes, I realized it after posting my answer. See my edited post

Answer (score 4):

For my significant projects, I have my own logging function that internally uses `console.log()`, but there are no `console.log()` calls in my code except for the one place in this function.  I can then enable or disable logging by changing one variable.

My function is actually a little more involved than this with options to put the output into places other than just the console, but conceptually, it looks like this:

```
// change this variable to false to globally turn off all logging
var myLoggingEnabled = true;   

function myLog() {
    if (myLoggingEnabled) {
        if (window.console && console.log) {
            console.log.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use code like this to log:

```
myLog(foo);
```

FYI, for deployed code compactness and performance optimization, I also have a minimization step that removes all calls to `myLog()` from my code.  This is an optimization that I've chosen to take advantage of.  Perhaps you could share why you wouldn't also consider this type of optimization.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Grunt you can add a task so as to remove/comment the console.log statements.
Therefore the console.log are no longer called.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-remove-logging-calls

Comment: I picked this module (e,g,, `grunt-remove-logging-calls`) over it's alternative `grunt-remove-logging`, since the latter one produced issues while replacing more complex console expressions

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I had a similar situation, I posted about it here. http://bhavinsurela.com/naive-way-of-overriding-console-log/
This is the gist of the code.

```
var domainNames =["fiddle.jshell.net"]; // we replace this by our production domain.

var logger = {
    force:false,
    original:null,
    log:function(obj)
    {
        var hostName = window.location.hostname;
        if(domainNames.indexOf(hostName) > -1)
        {
            if(window.myLogger.force === true)
            {
                window.myLogger.original.apply(this,arguments);
            }
        }else {
            window.myLogger.original.apply(this,arguments);
        }
    },
    forceLogging:function(force){
        window.myLogger.force = force;
    },
    original:function(){
        return window.myLogger.original;
    },
    init:function(){
        window.myLogger.original = console.log;
        console.log = window.myLogger.log;
    }
}

window.myLogger = logger;
console.log("this should print like normal");
window.myLogger.init();
console.log("this should not print");
window.myLogger.forceLogging(true);
console.log("this should print now");
```